# How to select result from dataframe according to specific pairs without iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to query (or loc) a sub-dataframe from a dataframe according to some specific pairs.

It is easy to use iteration to do this, but it is very slow.

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,5,6], [7,8,9], [2,3,8]], columns=['x','y','z'])
df
Out[4]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
2  7  8  9
3  2  3  8
```

I want to get a sub-dataframe where (x,y)=(1,2) and (x,y)=(1,5) and (x,y)=(2,3), like below

```py
Out[5]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
3  2  3  8
```

My method is to use iteration to get the indexes:

```py
xy_list=[(1,2),(1,5),(2,3)]
index_list=[]
for x,y in xy_list:
    index_list+=df.query('x==@x & y==@y').index.tolist()
df_sub=df.loc[index_list]
df_sub
Out[6]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
3  2  3  8
```

Is there any method to do this withou using iteration?

Comment: Where is the approach using iteration?

Comment: Please add pandas tag, it may be easier to get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you don't need to call `query` iteratively. Just build your query string using `str.join` and make a single `query` call after.

```
data = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3)]

pattern = '(' + ') | ('.join(f"x == {a} & y == {b}" for a, b in data) + ')'
pattern
# '(x == 1 & y == 2) | (x == 1 & y == 5) | (x == 2 & y == 3)'

df.query(pattern)

   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
3  2  3  8
```

---

Another option is using `Index.isin` and some filtering:

```
df[df.set_index(['x', 'y']).index.isin(data)]

   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
3  2  3  8
```

Alternatively, construct a MultiIndex using `MultiIndex.from_arrays`:

```
df[pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['x'], df['y']]).isin(data)]

   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
3  2  3  8
```

Same result, more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a very interesting answer. And I just edit the question, this is answer for the old version data. But it is correct!

Comment: @XiaojianChen Oh, added an option for filtering on the index that does not need to create a new dataframe.

Comment: Hi coldspeed! Thank you so much for your answer! I found the quey method is very good if there is some pairs are not in the dataframe! And the alternative method is a very good method to extend! I learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do a `df.set_index()` and `df.loc[]`:

```
xy_list=[(1,2),(1,5),(2,3)]
df_new=df.set_index(['x','y']).loc[xy_list].reset_index()
```

---

```
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  6
2  2  3  8
```

Comment: This is the best one if it is okay to make a new dataframe!

Comment: @XiaojianChen Thanks, you can change the existing df too if you want to... I retained the original one for safety purposes. :)